# Selecting and Storing DIVs on ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an App in which you select some products (DIVS) that changes the border color (with state). I would like to know how can I store these onClick actions, so that when people click on another link and comes back, the same DIVs are selected?

I know I can use Cookies or Sessions, but how to identify each DIV on React and make them auto-select once you refresh the page for example? How do you guys manage this? Thank you.

Comment: Which React version are you on?

Comment: I'm using Rekit studio right now. They don't have the react version on documentation, but I'll follow your advice and see how it goes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you

- have some products on your page that you're representing as `<div>` elements
- are changing their border on click
- want them to show as selected when the user refreshes the page

React is about the presentation of some data, but doesn't decide how you get that data onto the page. It sounds like you want to store the list of the *products selected* somewhere, then load that list onto the page again when the user refreshes. The [Web Storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) might be helpful, but cookies and sessions could do the same thing.

You need to

- choose what to store (probably a list of product ids)
- choose where to store it (localStorage, cookie, server, or maybe in the url with https://reach.tech/router)
- when your react page loads (`componentDidMount` for some component), read the list from localstorage into your state
- match your list of 'selected products' to your individual products in `render`

So, if you've loaded the list from one of the storage options into your state as `selectedProductIds` and your list of products is in state as `products`

```
isSelected = (product) => {
   this.state.selectedProductIds.includes(product.id)
}

render() {
  return <section>
    { this.state.products.map((product) =>
        <div className={this.isSelected(product) ? 'selected item' : 'item'}>
           {product.name}
        </div>
    )}
  </section>
}
```

Keeping React state in sync with some other storage mechanism can get pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep state after reloads you might want to take a look at `HTML Web Storage`.

Answer (score 1):

In order of preference I would use:

1) If you are on react 16.3 or greater use the react context api
2) If you are not on 16.3 or greater you can use a library such as redux or flux
3) you can use HTML local storage.

Here is more info on Redux vs context api:
https://daveceddia.com/context-api-vs-redux/

Web storage is the least desirable because it doesn't enforce any rules around state management like the other options do.

Comment: tho you still need to persist your storage with in `localStorage` for it to last over full page refresh.

Comment: Well it depends on what exactly he means by "so that when people click on another link and comes back, the same DIVs are selected?".  If he means navigation within his own site then he doesn't need to store in localStorage.

Comment: True as well. In case of using Redux could recommend check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist and just to point out that if actual persistency on page refresh is not required (as if only navigating through pages would count), this could be solved as easily as to just store values to an state of `higher order component` which then passes it's state as props to an child components. Also I discourage to use `Redux` or `React Context API` for simple tasks.

Comment: I agree that an HOC will solve it and redux-persist is a great tool.  That said I was thinking based on the wording of the question in addition to the fact that OP doesn't know which version of react he is using that HOCs may be a bit too advanced of a topic but definitely worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

Here, an example with local storage:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { list: null };
  }

  onSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { value } = this.input;

    if (value === '') {
      return;
    }

    const cached = localStorage.getItem(value);
    if (cached) {
      this.setState({ list: JSON.parse(cached) });
      return;
    }

    fetch('https://search?query=' + value)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        localStorage.setItem(value, JSON.stringify(result.list));
        this.setState({ list: result.list });
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <form type="submit" onSubmit={this.onSearch}>
          <input type="text" ref={node => this.input = node} />
          <button type="button">Search</button>
        </form>

        {
          this.state.list &&
          this.state.list.map(item => <div key={item.objectID}>{item.title}</div>)
        }
      </div>
  }

}
```